# How can I use .NET web services from non-standard ports?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, web-services

Our web services are accessed through a router which uses port forwarding to connect to the actual web server.  When we are trying to establish a web reference in Visual Studio it seems the .NET framework returns the full URL with a port to Visual Studio for the reference during discovery.  Visual Studio then tries to make a connection back to that web service to create a proxy object (or whatever) and is denied because we don't allow access on that non-standard port.

Original web service URL

```
http://webservices.example.com/SomeService.asmx
```

Returned web service URL from router

```
http://webservices.example.com:25001/SomeService.asmx
```

My question is if you know how to make the .NET framework NOT include the port when returning the URL from the discovery call.  Here's a diagram depicting this process:

[image: diagram]

Comment: are you trying to connect to a WCF service or a .net web service?

Comment: @Ian - Your diagram doesn't render, site just times out.

Comment: is anyone else getting a time out on the image?  I've tried from multiple computers and am not having a problem. (thx Kev)

Comment: @Ian - Looks like it's my home DSL ISP that's hiding it. I can see it now via RDP to our corp network.

Comment: @Ian - I've popped some more thoughts down about this problem in my answer.

Comment: If the application is already in production, then why is any discovery going on? I don't see this making sense. When is the router informing the client of the URL with the new port? This isn't a redirect (302) situation.

Comment: The discovery occurs when making a web reference in VS.  Perhaps "discovery" isn't the right word.

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick:

> [Manually setting soap:address in ASMX](http://blogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/archive/2005/11/16/414319.aspx)

Here's the code snippet just in case the link dies:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Services.Description;

namespace Thinktecture.Tools.Web.Services.Metadata
{
  public class SoapAddressReflector : SoapExtensionReflector
  {
    public override void ReflectMethod()
    {
      ServiceDescription sd = ReflectionContext.ServiceDescription;

      foreach (Service service in sd.Services)
      {
        foreach (Port port in service.Ports)
        {
          foreach (ServiceDescriptionFormatExtension extension in port.Extensions)
          {
            if (extension is SoapAddressBinding)
            {
              SoapAddressBinding address = (SoapAddressBinding)extension;

              // Set the address here:
              address.Location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SoapAddress"];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Config:

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
  <add key="SoapAddress" value="http://www.thinktecture.com/Test/"/>
 </appSettings>

 <system.web>
  <webServices>
    <soapExtensionReflectorTypes>
      <add type="Thinktecture.Tools.Web.Services.Metadata.SoapAddressReflector, SoapAddressReflector"/>
    </soapExtensionReflectorTypes>
  </webServices>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Update:**

The technique above seems to work just fine but has some limitations if you have more than one service. You also need to be running in Full Trust so doing this in a partial trust environment isn't going to work.

I'm not sure there's any other magic config switch or attribute to make this happen other than using the [`SoapExtensionReflector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.soapextensionreflector.aspx). After a good Google around, all the results point to the SoapExtensionReflector method.

But how about this? If the web services don't change all that often you could take a copy of the generated WDSL, edit the SOAP/HTTP bindings, and then publish it on it's own as a static XML file?

Comment: Thanks Kev.  We do have multiple services within the app.  I'm hoping there's a config setting we can update to not include the port or something.  wishful thinking probably :).

Comment: Thank you for the additional info.  Our app is already in production but the network architecture is changing a bit.  We really want to avoid changing the app itself if at all humanly possible.  +1 for the added info and extra effort.  Thanks!