# Fix non-standard web serverice port on contractRef and docRef

Tags: wsdl, asmx, service-discovery

My problem is closely related to this one: [How can I use .NET web services from non-standard ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640641/how-can-i-use-net-web-services-from-non-standard-ports).  My web service runs behind a port-forwarding firewall, so the port numbers reported in the WSDL document contain the internal high-numbered port.  I wrote a SoapExtensionReflector class which is able to rewrite the WSDL document.  So a request like example.com/path/loginservice?wsdl is handled correctly.

However, this doesn't handle the "disco" request: example.com/path/loginservice?disco.  This returns an XML document like this:

```
<discovery>
  <contractRef ref="http://example.com:10092/loginservice.asmx?wsdl" docRef="http://example.com:10092/loginservice.asmx"/>
  <soap address="http://example.com/path/loginservice.asmx" binding="q1:LoginServiceSoap"/>
  <soap address="http://example.com/path/loginservice.asmx" binding="q2:LoginServiceSoap12"/>
</discovery>
```

While the soap bindings have been properly re-written by the SoapExtensionReflector, the contractRef and docRef URLs have the high-numbered port.  How can I rewrite them as well?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured something out. Created proxy classes manually using svcutil after migrating everything to WCF. I figure you could probably do the same thing using the wsdl tool that came with the old asp.net web services, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: I didn't find a fix.  I switched to WCF.  I still had to write extensions to fix the port issue, using WCFExtras.  That cleans up the WSDL, but I still have the port number showing on the .svc web page, though it's fairly harmless there.